# Hash table problems with values getting overwritten

Tags: c, list, struct, hashtable

I am testing for the very first time hash tables and I get such a weird error.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 40

typedef struct snode {
    char *nome;
    struct snode *next;
} TNode;

typedef TNode *TList;

typedef struct tht {
    TList *buckets;
    int nbuckets;
} THT;

TList Create_List();
TNode *Create_Node(char *);
TList Insert_List(TList, char *);
THT *Create_THT(int n);
void HT_Print(THT *ht);
THT *Insert_THT(THT *ht, char *name, int key);
int hash(char *name);
void Print_List(TList list);

int main() {
    THT *ht = Create_THT(5);
    char name[MAX];
    int key, contr;
    printf("INSERISCI 0 PER USCIRE O INSERIRE NOME \n");
    do {
        printf("\n INSERIRE NOME : ");
        scanf("%s", &name);  //AFTER THE SECOND INSERTION FROM THIS LANE VALUES CHANGE INSIDE ht?? why 
        key = hash(name);
        ht = Insert_THT(ht, name, key);
        printf("\n Inserisci 1 per continuare 0 per terminare ");
        scanf("%d", &contr);

    } while (contr != 0);
    HT_Print(ht);
    return 0;
}

TList Create_List() {
    return NULL;
}

TNode *Create_Node(char nome[MAX]) {
    TNode *node;
    node = malloc(sizeof(TNode));
    node->nome = nome;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

TList Insert_List(TList list, char info[MAX]) {
    TNode *tmp;
    TNode *node;
    node = Create_Node(info);
    tmp = list;
    if (list == NULL) {
        list = node;
    } else {
        while (tmp->next != NULL) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = node;
    }
    return list;
}

THT *Create_THT(int n) {
    int i;
    THT *ht = malloc(sizeof(THT));

    ht->buckets = malloc(n * sizeof(TList));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ht->buckets[i] = Create_List();
    }
    ht->nbuckets = n;
    return ht;
}

void HT_Print(THT *ht) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ht->nbuckets; i++) {
        Print_List(ht->buckets[i]);
    }
}

int hash(char *name) {
    return (name[0] - 'a');
}

THT *Insert_THT(THT *ht, char name[MAX], int key) {
    ht->buckets[key] = Insert_List(ht->buckets[key], name);
    return ht;
}

void Print_List(TList list) {
    while (list != NULL) {
        printf("%s", list->nome);
        list = list->next;
    }
}
```

I tested it with the debug. It's ok at  the first insertion (for example I insert `adam`) but then something weird happens. 
The second time when I give as input the name like `bob` for example (since it's like a vocabulary of names) and I check the value of `ht->buckets` something changes inside.

I dont understand I didn't even get into the functions that modify effectively what's inside my hash table (`ht`) and inside it changes . I am getting crazy and I tried to find a solution but I really dont understand how from a command in a main that doesn't have to deal with my HT's struct values change inside that struct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unrelated, but using English names and outputs makes it easier for everybody.

---

Just a guess, but inside `Create_Node`, you allocate memory for the new node but don't allocate memory for the name (`nome`).

You just copy the pointer to the passed array, which changes every time you insert a new name. Allocating memory for the name and copying the contents instead of the pointer should resolve this issue, e.g.

```
node->nome = strdup(nome);
```

Don't forget, that when you use the hash in a larger context, you must cleanup the hash and names eventually, which means freeing the memory for the nodes and names

```
free(node->nome);
free(node);
```

---

`Create_Node` receives a pointer to the array `name` in `main`. This array is reused every time a new name is input. This means, all nodes point to the same array, and so all nodes print the same (last input) name.

Allocating individual memory for each node and copying the array to this memory ([`strdup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html)), solves the problem.

Comment: what library should i include for that function ??

Comment: in which part of the code should i free the memory for the node->name and the node itself?

Comment: You have `Create_*` functions, and you need `Destroy_*` functions, where you cleanup the hash structures. You need these functions, when you don't need the hash anymore.

Comment: I made the correction you suggested and the program does what it should . I don't know if i understood what the problem is but running the debug with the old code (maybe) i found out  that when i initialiazed the node with node->name =name it took the address of the first character of the string name that I insert via input which didnt change for the nexts' insertions. So it overwrote all the other names' insertions . Correct me if im wrong

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems in your code:

- You hide pointers behind typedefs in `typedef TNode *TList;` This is error prone and confusing for readers of your code.
- `CreateNode` does not make a copy of the memory pointed to by `name`. Given how you use this function, all nodes share the same array, so all nodes have the same name. Use `node->nome = strdup(nome);` to solve this problem.
- `scanf("%s", &name);` is incorrect: the `&` is superfluous and you should specify the maximum number of characters to store to `name` to avoid buffer overflows. Use `scanf("%39s", name);`. Furthermore, you should test the return value to detect unexpected end of file.
- `Print_List` does not separate the names. Use `printf("%s\n", list->nome)` to output them on separate lines.
- You should free the hash table at the end of the program:

```c
void Free_THT(THT *ht) {
    if (ht) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < ht->nbuckets; i++) {
            TNode *list = ht->buckets[i];
            ht->buckets[i] = NULL;
            while (list != NULL) {
                TNode *node = list;
                list = list->next;
                free(node->name);
                free(node);
            }
        }
        free(ht->buckets);
        free(ht);
    }
}
```

Comment: the second point is what i needed i wrote the code without optimizing it i knew about the other errors but i just wanted to solve the overwritting problem . Thx for the answer